# '(OS Error: File name too long, errno = 63)' Build errors while running flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, build

I am getting this error while trying to build or running my flutter app. Its kinda frustrating as I don't seem to know where the issue lie.

```
 +9 ms] [  +15 ms] Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to
    '/Users/User/FlutterProjects/heala_patient_app/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/androi
    d/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_asset
    s/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutt
    er_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/deb
    ug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flu
    tter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/android/app/build
    /intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flut
    ter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/
    merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/.env
    ', path =
    '/Users/User/FlutterProjects/heala_patient_app/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/androi
    d/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_asset
    s/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutt
    er_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/deb
    ug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/mer
    ged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/android
    /app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debu
    g/out/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/android/app/build/inte
    rmediates/merged_assets/debug/out/flutter_assets/.env' (OS Error: File name too long, errno = 63)
```

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean` and rebuilding it again?

Answer (score -1):

remove `android/build` folder and re-run